# How is the optical conductivity for a single photon related to normal conductivity?

Tags: visible-light, photons

Planck argued that light energy is carried by photons. The electric optical conductivity for an electromagnetic wave is classically derived. How does this conductivity look like for single photons (when they behave as particles)?

Comment: What is "electric optical conductivity" supposed to mean for single photons?

Comment: Do you mean "What do the Fresnel equations look for single photons?"?